# Factoring a positive-definite integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, integers, positive-definite

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a symmetric positive-definite matrix whose entries happen to be integers. We can write $$M = R^T R$$ with some invertible matrix $R \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ which is not unique by any means.

Usually we can't choose $R$ to be integral. Even multiplying $M$ by a scalar (integer) and trying to solve $$a M = R^T R$$ with $R \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}$ is impossible in general when $n$ is even because $$a^n \mathrm{det}(M) = \mathrm{det}(a M) = \mathrm{det}(R^T R) = \mathrm{det}(R)^2$$ would force $\mathrm{det}(M)$ to be square.

This restriction does not happen when $n$ is odd. Question: given $M$ as above, if $n$ is odd, can we always find a scalar $a$ such that $aM$ has the form $R^T R$ with $R \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let 
$$
M =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
One of your forms,  is going to be anisotropic in the 2-adic numbers but isotropic in all other $p$-adic numbers. This one, the reverse situation, is isotropic in the $2$-adics, but anisotropic in the $3$-adic numbers.

Give it a try, by your methods.

Analogous, even though the determinant is already a square:
$$
N =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 10
\end{array}
\right)
$$